# How to link CSS and Jade?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

Server.js file code given below

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var PORT = 8080;

app.set('views', './public/views');

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index.jade'); 
});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Express listening on port: '+PORT);
});
```

Index.jade file provided below

```
html
    head
        title Upload file for shortening
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
        h1 Welcome to file metadata service
        div(id="submit-button")
            form(action = '/submit')
                button(type="submit", value='Submit')
```

style.css file provided below

```
#submit-button{
    height:100px;
}

h1{
    font-family:Impact;
}
```

I have created a public folder in my root directory, and then a views folder. Inside the views folder is where the index.jade file is saved, and inside of another folder inside the views folder, called the stylesheets folder is where the CSS file is saved.

However, any time I try to run my app, it fails to load the CSS file. Why is this happening?

Comment: I think the path is wrong. If the `stylesheets` folder and `index.jade` is in the `views` folder then your href value should read `stylesheets/style.css` ... Remove the `/` from the href.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange - Hey, that didn't work. I still get a 404 Error when i try to run the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put this line in `layout.jade` file if exists
>   `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')`

and import `layout.jade` in your `HTML` file with this line at top of the page `extends layout`

here `layout.jade` file..

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the layout.jade file? Is that my index.jade file?

Comment: It's separate file where we link all the `CSS`, `JS` files

Comment: I tried doing that. But now, nothing happens. Absolutely nothing loads on to the server page and it doesn't throw any errors either

Comment: Yeah, I did. The moment I remove the extends layout from the index.jade file, the server returns the display. But again, without any CSS styling

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be too late to answer; I faced the same issue and was able to resolve using `style`.

```html
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    style
        include ../stylesheets/style.css
  body
    block content
```